# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan x dx=\frac{π}{8}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> For $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function with the property that $2f(\frac{1-x}{1+x})=(1+x)^2$. Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan xdx=\frac{π}{8}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)$.

However, I obtained that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan xdx=\int_{0}^{1} 2f\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\arctan\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)dt=\frac{π}{4}-\int_{0}^{1}\arctan tdt$$ Which is $\frac{\ln 2}{2}$. However $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$ after similar changes in variable. The results don't match, in conclusion.

Edit: I copied the exercise correctly. I post a photo of it, sorry for being in Romanian.[image]

Comment: I believe you copied the exercise wrong. You missed out an $f(x)$.

Comment: Indeed, it would be a good idea to inform the author. Although I see there the year  is $1999$ so it might be kinda late.

Comment: @RobertZ It's from the supliment of  ,,Gazeta Matematica", no. 1, 2019,

Comment: @Zacky I think the same if indeed the mistake is in the original exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you meant:$$2f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=\color{orange}{f(x)}(1+x)^2$$ 
We can start with the given integral and let $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\Rightarrow dx=-\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}dt$ $$I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan xdx=\int_0^1 \color{blue}{f\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}\color{red}{\arctan \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{(1+t)^2}dt$$
$$=\int_0^1 \color{blue}{f(t)}\left(\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan t}\right)dt\overset{t=x}=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 f(x)dx-I$$
$$\Rightarrow 2I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 f(x)dx \Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^1 f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct but, as Zacky pointed out, a factor $f(x)$ is missing in the stated property of $f$.

Let $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$, then $dx=\frac{-2dt}{(1+t^2)}$, $$\arctan(x)=\arctan(1)-\arctan(t),$$ 
and, by using the given property $2f(x)=f(t)(1+t)^2$ (**with $f$**), we get
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)(\arctan(1)-\arctan(t))dt\\
=
\frac{\pi}{4}\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt-\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\arctan(t))\,dt$$
which implies that
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_{0}^{1}f(t)\,dt.$$

Comment: How did you got this:$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)(\arctan(1)-\arctan(t))dt?$$With: $2f\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)=(1+t)^2$

Comment: With that substitution, one gets: $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan xdx=\int_0^1 2{f\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{\arctan \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}\frac{{1}}{(1+t)^2}dt$$ Or I'm wrong? How there is  still left with an $f(t)$ after you replace $2f\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)$ with $(1+t)^2$?

Comment: I obtain that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\arctan(x)\,dx is \int_{0}^{1}f(\frac{1-t}{1+t})(\arctan(1)-\arctan(t))dt\\$.

Comment: However, considering Zacky's suggestion, your solution is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the statement. Yes a correction is needed!

Comment: No worries! One small mistake:$\  dx=\frac{-\color{red}{2}dt}{(1+t)^\color{red}2}$

Comment: Thanks, again (+1)!